# Send 02 string from a siemens s7-1500 to a zebra printer

Tags: plc, zebra-printers, scada, zebra-scanners

I have a plc s7-1500 and a zebra zt410 printer. I've made them communicate by TCP/IP and everything is working. But the problem is that, the ZPL code of my label is too long and has more than 254 characters (which is the limit for a String).

So, I've made a small ladder program, who changes the data of the TSEND_C block after a delay, but nothing.

I think there is a ZPL character or command I have to add at the end of the first string I'm sending and at the beginning of the second, to tell the printer that those two strings should be considered like just one.

I've tried `^`, `\r\n`, `'`, but nothing.

Comment: The printer doesn't care how many packets make up the label format.  It is looking for the `^XA` to start the format and `^XZ` to end it.  Everything that comes between is simply concatenated together.  Does the DATA LED on the printer light up when you send the format?  And stay lit?  If so, the printer is waiting on more ZPL.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. I managed to print with the 02 string of zpl program, but it works 1 time on 2 don't know why